# Speeding up TableLayoutPanel

Tags: .net, vb.net

I have several nested TableLayoutPanels in a winform. It took a VERY long time to paint(?) them and such, so I've used this code to make it almost instantaneous (it is a double buffered TableLayoutPanel):

```
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices

Public Class CoTableLayoutPanel
    Inherits TableLayoutPanel
    Protected Overrides Sub OnCreateControl()
        MyBase.OnCreateControl()
        Me.SetStyle(ControlStyles.OptimizedDoubleBuffer Or ControlStyles.CacheText, True)
    End Sub

    Protected Overrides ReadOnly Property CreateParams() As CreateParams
        Get
            Dim cp As CreateParams = MyBase.CreateParams
            cp.ExStyle = cp.ExStyle Or NativeMethods.WS_EX_COMPOSITED
            Return cp
        End Get
    End Property

    Public Sub BeginUpdate()
        NativeMethods.SendMessage(Me.Handle, NativeMethods.WM_SETREDRAW, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero)
    End Sub

    Public Sub EndUpdate()
        NativeMethods.SendMessage(Me.Handle, NativeMethods.WM_SETREDRAW, New IntPtr(1), IntPtr.Zero)
        Parent.Invalidate(True)
    End Sub
End Class

Public NotInheritable Class NativeMethods
    Private Sub New()
    End Sub
    Public Shared WM_SETREDRAW As Integer = &HB
    'uint WM_SETREDRAW
    Public Shared WS_EX_COMPOSITED As Integer = &H2000000


    <DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet:=CharSet.Auto)>
    Public Shared Function SendMessage(hWnd As IntPtr, Msg As Integer, wParam As IntPtr, lParam As IntPtr) As IntPtr
    End Function
    'UInt32 Msg
End Class
```

This works very nicely when the form is resized and when I use this next code to resize the rows, it works very fast as well:

```
TableLayoutPanel1.RowStyles(0) = New RowStyle(SizeType.Percent, 100)
TableLayoutPanel1.RowStyles(1) = New RowStyle(SizeType.Percent, 0)
TableLayoutPanel1.RowStyles(2) = New RowStyle(SizeType.Percent, 0)
TableLayoutPanel1.RowStyles(3) = New RowStyle(SizeType.Percent, 0)
TableLayoutPanel1.RowStyles(4) = New RowStyle(SizeType.Percent, 0)
TableLayoutPanel1.RowStyles(5) = New RowStyle(SizeType.Percent, 0)
TableLayoutPanel1.RowStyles(6) = New RowStyle(SizeType.Percent, 0)
TableLayoutPanel1.RowStyles(7) = New RowStyle(SizeType.Percent, 0)
TableLayoutPanel2.RowStyles(0) = New RowStyle(SizeType.AutoSize)
```

The trouble is when I set them back to their original sizes:

```
TableLayoutPanel1.RowStyles(0) = New RowStyle(SizeType.Percent, 12.5)
TableLayoutPanel1.RowStyles(1) = New RowStyle(SizeType.Percent, 12.5)
TableLayoutPanel1.RowStyles(2) = New RowStyle(SizeType.Percent, 12.5)
TableLayoutPanel1.RowStyles(3) = New RowStyle(SizeType.Percent, 12.5)
TableLayoutPanel1.RowStyles(4) = New RowStyle(SizeType.Percent, 12.5)
TableLayoutPanel1.RowStyles(5) = New RowStyle(SizeType.Percent, 12.5)
TableLayoutPanel1.RowStyles(6) = New RowStyle(SizeType.Percent, 12.5)
TableLayoutPanel1.RowStyles(7) = New RowStyle(SizeType.Percent, 12.5)
TableLayoutPanel2.RowStyles(0) = New RowStyle(SizeType.Percent, 28.15)
```

Using this code, it seems like they should resize with the same speed, but it doesn't, and is noticeably much laggier. Does anyone have any suggestions as to what I can do to make the resize just as fast?

Comment: Before you bothered with the PInvokes and such, did you try to simply `SuspendLayout()` and `ResumeLayout()` ?  It is usually enough with that type of isssue.

Comment: @Plutonix I did try Suspend and Resume before and it wasn't working very well. In this instance though, it works perfectly. If you would be so kind as to just put something as an answer, I would be very happy to mark it as the answer!